# Can't pass in YAML Values using Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, yaml

I have a config.yml file that looks like this

```
---
name:
  archive:
    documentfiles:
      username: rafa
      password: hello
```

my Configuration looks like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "name")
public class YamlConfig {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

In my test class, I try to get the first value from the List that is returned, but it returns an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` so I know that the `config.yml` values, are not passed in. Can anyone offer some help? Below is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class OfflineFileViewerResourceTest {
     @Test
    public void password(){
        fileViewer = new OfflineFileViewerResource();
        YamlConfig yaml = new YamlConfig();
        List<String> list = yaml.getServers();

        assertEquals("archive", list.get(0));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of Spring annotations (e.g. `@ConfigurationProperties`) won't work when you're creating beans manually (with `new`):

```
YamlConfig yaml = new YamlConfig();
```

To accomplish what you need, you should allow Spring manage beans and inject them from `ApplicationContext` into your tests.